# Calculating the week number for a date, when your year starts on a non 1st January day

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the week number for a given date, when my year begins on the 1st of May.

My hope was to use `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()`, which applies the rules I need, but by overriding the first day of year in a `Calendar` that derives from say, `GregorianCalendar`.

Unfortunately I can't find a way of doing this. Adding an arbitrary 122 / 123 days to the date in question will break the `GetWeekOfYear()` `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` rule I wish to use.

Short of writing a custom and I suspect messy algorithm to determine this, is there a way of calculating the week number for a given date, when my year begins on the 1st of May?

Comment: So...what is the question then?

Comment: I'll rephrase the question to clarify, but 'How do I configure a Calendar object, or `GetWeekOfYear()` when my year starts on a non 1st January day?

Comment: Configure it to do what exactly? the year still starts on January 1st, regardless of which subset of it you need to take as valid

Comment: Perhaps I've conflated my question with my perceived idea of the solution. I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use this approach which simply subtracts the 121 days from  January 1st to May 1st from a given `DateTime` and then uses `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` on that date:

```
static readonly int DayOffset = (new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 5, 1) 
                               - new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)).Days; // 121

// ... somewhere else:
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
DateTime offsetDate = date.AddDays(-DayOffset);
int weekNum = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(offsetDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday); 
Console.WriteLine("Year:{0} Week:{1}", offsetDate.Year, weekNum); // Year:2016 Week:19
```

Comment: I wondered about this, but would this cause problems with the`CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek`, where the 1st May and 1st January would land on different days of the week?

Comment: @SimonB: Yes, that's possible. So you need addtional logic to find the right offset for your needs. It depends on whether the date to check is before or after the 1st of may because before means one year before and you have to look on which date that year "began". If it was f.e. 3rd of january you have to subtract 119 instead of 121 days.

Comment: I agree. I think i'll start with your snippet and add a bunch of test cases until I'm happy with the extra logic! I'll mark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonB Instead of subtracting the number of days, subtract the thing you care about: the number of weeks. Use `GetWeekOfYear` for May 1st, and subtract that number from the day you care about. E.g., `GetWeekOfYear(May 10th) - GetWeekOfYear(May 1st) + 1` will always come out as `2`, even if May 1st is 20th week of some year instead of the 21st (or whatever) (also add one so it's not zero based).

Comment: @Quantic this is a great pointer, thanks. I've added an answer, which is what I've ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this, which works but doesn't handle the week 53 scenario:

```
    private int calculateBizWeekNumber(DateTime date, DateTime yearStart, CalendarWeekRule cwr, DayOfWeek firstDoW)
    {
        var cal = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;

        var dateWoY = cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, cwr, firstDoW);
        var firstWoY = cal.GetWeekOfYear(yearStart, cwr, firstDoW);

        var bizWeek = dateWoY - firstWoY + 1;

        return bizWeek <= 0 ? 52 + bizWeek : bizWeek;
    }
```